# Compare date values in expression using govaluate

Tags: go, expression, rule-engine

I am trying to build a rule engine using govaluate: https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Knetic/govaluate"
    "fmt"
)

func main()  {
    expression, err := govaluate.NewEvaluableExpression("first_name == 'Julian' && emp_id == 302 && birth_date >= '2016-12-12' && birth_date <= '2016-12-25'")

    parameters := make(map[string]interface{}, 8)
    parameters["first_name"] = "Julian"
    parameters["emp_id"] = 302
    parameters["birth_date"] = "2016-12-15"
    result, err := expression.Evaluate(parameters)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while evaluating the expression")
    }

    if result.(bool) {
        fmt.Println("Condition is evaluated to true")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Condition is evaluated to false")
    }
}
```

While browsing through govaluate Types documentation (https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate/blob/master/MANUAL.md), I noticed this statement "*Any string literal (not parameter) which is interpretable as a date will be converted to a float64 representation of that date's unix time.*"

When i execute the above program, i see an issue with result being null:

```
Error while evaluating the expression
panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not bool
```

My question is whether date value can be passed in as a parameter? As i want to compare date values in runtime, this functionality would be needed.

Is there a way to achieve it? May be my usage pattern is wrong. Please suggest.

**Edit:**

```
expression, err := govaluate.NewEvaluableExpression("first_name == 'Julian' && emp_id == 302 && birth_date >= '2016-12-12' && birth_date <= '2016-12-25'")
dateFloat, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("2016-12-15", 64)
parameters["birth_date"] = dateFloat
result, err := expression.Evaluate(parameters)
```

Changed the date to float format and invoked Evaluate function. Now the condition is evaluated to false. But logically,  2016-12-15 falls between 2016-12-12 and 2016-12-25. The expression should be evaluated to true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment on your example. Your example `birth_date` is `2017` but your query is `>= 2016... AND <= 2016....`

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that! Corrected it.

Comment: Comment to your edit. See what all three dates evaluate to after `strconv.ParseFloat`-ing them. Also, note that the README is not talking about the `strconv.ParseFloat` representation, but the `time` package's representation. Specifically the `Unix()` function representation.

Comment: Ohh.. All three date constants are all evaluating to value 0 on passing to strconv.ParseFloat("{value}", 64). 

My use case is that input birth_date that i receive from REST call has to be evaluated against this expression. Trying to figure out a way using parameters in govaluate. 
Another way would be to write a custom function

Comment: It seems that the documentation is saying that the query is correct, but in your map you need the `time.Parse().Unix()` value of the date, not the string value of the date. P.S. That's what you get for ignoring the `error` return value of `ParseFloat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-posting my answer from [the associated github issue](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate/issues/62), for future googlers;

The library doesn't try to parse string parameters as dates - it expects that `birth_date` will be the [`Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix) value of that date. This means you'll have to parse the date before passing it to govaluate.

If you're getting `birth_date` as part of a REST api, I'd suggest settling on one specific date format (such as ISO8601) and doing something like:

```
var birthDateString string // <-- the birth_date string you get from the request

iso8601 := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z0700"

birthDate, err := time.ParseInLocation(iso8601, birthDateString, 
time.Local)
parameters["birth_date"] = birthDate.Unix()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Knetic/govaluate"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    expression, err := govaluate.NewEvaluableExpression("first_name == 'Julian' && emp_id == 302 && birth_date >= '2016-12-15' && birth_date <= '2016-12-25'")

    parameters := make(map[string]interface{}, 8)
    parameters["first_name"] = "Julian"
    parameters["emp_id"] = 302
    iso8601 := "2006-01-02"
    birthDate, err := time.ParseInLocation(iso8601, "2016-12-15", time.Local)
    parameters["birth_date"] = birthDate.Unix()
    result, err := expression.Evaluate(parameters)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while evaluating the expression")
    }

    if result.(bool) {
        fmt.Println("Condition is evaluated to true")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Condition is evaluated to false")
    }
}
```

Thank you Library owner and @RayfenWindspear for helping me out on this! Really appreciate!